# Why is not possible to transform a Promise in immutable data with ImmutableJs?

Tags: promise, immutable.js

I'm using immutable.js to transform my data, but i can't do it with javaScript promises. Is it correct to use immutable with Promises? Or it's a library bug?

version:
"immutable": "3.8.1",

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. It would help to understand better.

You cannot transform promise object with immutable.js. You can transform only the data returned by the promise.

Comment: If immutable.js can't work with Promises, that would be, at worst, a constraint not a bug.

Comment: @Jebin, thanks for the answer. The data come from my promise i can transform in immutable data, it's' right now.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I understand. I search in documentation and google for something associated with promises, but i can't found anything, but how you speak before, it's just a constraint

Comment: @EduardoAugusto, it's just a matter of words, but sometimes words help get things straight in one's head.

Answer (score 0):

For any one who comes here for answer:

You cannot transform a promise object with immutable.js. You can only transform the data returned by the promise using immutable.js.

This is wrong and you should not convert a promise to immutable object.

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');

const promise = getData();
const map1 = Map(promise);
```

Following is correct and you should convert the data returned by the promise to an immutable object.

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');

const data = await getData();
const map1 = Map(data);
```